# Copy text with new lines to clipboard

Tags: javascript

I have the following function, but when the text contains new line character "\r\n", it is not copied to the clipboard. What am I doing wrong?

```
function copyToClipboard(text) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val(text).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An input do not have newlines, try to instantiate your $temp as a textarea instead.